# Safari browser logout issue windows authentication

Tags: javascript, asp.net, safari

After logout page, if user doesn't close the browser window and return to site again, no authentication box is displayed, because the username and password are stored on browser cache.

In IE, document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache") is working fine. but this does not seems to work with safari.

I have tried the following options,

1) `Response.Statuscode=401` (from server side)- This clear the authentication cache and gives the credential popup, but it's not accepting even if we give correct credentials. If we click on cancel and try to access the page again then it works fine.

2) Using `XMLHttpRequestfrom` Client - When I try to open the URL on the same site with blank crendentials, the readyState and statuscode always returns 0

```
 function testfn() {
        alert("send completed");
        alert(XMLHttp1.readyState);
    }
    function run()
    {
        XMLHttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        XMLHttp1.onreadystatechange = testfn();
        XMLHttp1.open('GET', 'http://172.22.164.253/test/testxml.xml', true, '_', '_');
        try {
            XMLHttp1.wi
            XMLHttp1.send();
            alert("sent");
            alert("status" + XMLHttp1.status);
            alert(XMLHttp1.status == 401) ;
            } 
        catch (ex) {
            alert("Exception: Got an exception. " + ex);
        }
    }
```

3) Clear Cache - Tried all the below code with various combination, but no luck

```
Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires =-1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";

Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Page.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Please advise me on the solution to logout from Safari while working on ASP.NET pages with windows authentication.

Comment: Hi, does the same occur in Google Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: ok, I delete the answer to see by others and I think again what I miss here...

Comment: Yes, on the chrome. I didn't check on firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logout through XMLHTTPRequest Object is not working in Opera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619480/logout-through-xmlhttprequest-object-is-not-working-in-opera)